# Is there any way to fetch userid from username in google+ using googleapi?

Tags: android, ios, google-api, google-plus, google-apis-explorer

is there any possibility to find userid from the username in google plus.?
I want to fetch activities of the user by its username.

i.e. Username is "`+LarryPage`" then i need its userid to fetch its activities. But there is no way to identify userid by username. activities by username. 
Activities are only available if we know the userid.

If it is not available then `GooglePlus` team needs to add this functionality to find out atleast userid from the username.

There is a api to search the people. But it is not feasible. because it checks only `displayName` which can be same for too many people.

I have attached the response to find LarryPage in googleplus api. But not able to identify who is the right one.

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"xoxof0VSFbg0RVYwDJMmg4Jxcp4/PNuMC_dEeZTZ-kScKTd8paGuyXg\"",
   "objectType": "person",
   "id": "106189723444098348646",
   "displayName": "Larry Page",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/+LarryPage",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Y86IN-vEObo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAADO1I/QzjOGHq5kNQ/photo.jpg?sz=50"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"xoxof0VSFbg0RVYwDJMmg4Jxcp4/zMTOKX19L3IKS43Bv3m6xV0dLNM\"",
   "objectType": "person",
   "id": "111176035772651881663",
   "displayName": "Larry Page",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/111176035772651881663",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-AFDqJCHiTuA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEE/oMOpCoPpfy0/photo.jpg?sz=50"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"xoxof0VSFbg0RVYwDJMmg4Jxcp4/soC0nCQRAJ8gFoxvRJnf4iwMSB0\"",
   "objectType": "person",
   "id": "101600523208878203536",
   "displayName": "Larry Page",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/101600523208878203536",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UHYp8q4snW0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACWs/BRe354a0WfU/photo.jpg?sz=50"
   }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually use `userId` and their `+username` interchangeably. For example with [People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) it's documented as:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId
```

or with a real `userId`:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/106189723444098348646
```

but switching to a username works just fine:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/+LarryPage
```

It works the same way with [Activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/+LarryPage/activities/public
```

Comment: Thanks. @arbaham ur answer is really helpful to me. Thanks again.